# Using windows scheduler to run python script with inputs

Tags: python, windows, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have a difficult problem. I want to setup windows scheduler to run a python script every day. To make my program simple, I want to:

```
start with input 10 today, add 5, return 15
start with yesterday's return, add 5, return the value (start with 15, add 5, return 20)
......
etc
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could write the return to a text file then the next day the program reads the text file and starts with the number it reads from the text file  then re-writes the new value to the text file

this way you can save data while the program isnt running and retreive it later

Hope that help :)

Comment: So you are saying to run python, take input from text file, manipulate input, then write out to the same text file. How would the value in the text file be overwritten? or How would you get the most recent value?

Comment: well at the beginning of your prog you read the number in the number in the text file then you use that as the start number then you add 5 and when you re-write the file it automatically rewrites the old number

Answer (score 0):

Create a .py file with your code in it. You can keep track of the numbers in a text file or XML document and read/parse as necessary on a daily basis, then overwrite, pass it as an argument (data.txt or xml). Create it initially with the starting value.

I'd format it as XML, since Python has a bunch of nice XML Parsers.

```
<xml>
    <data>10</data>
</xml>
```

Drop the following into a batch or cmd file (.bat, .cmd)

```
c:\<path_to_python>\python.exe c:\<full_path>\yourfile.py c:\<full_path>\data.xml
```

Schedule the batch to run in Windows Scheduler using proper credentials.